# Keeping Python from spacing after breaking a line when printing a List

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, line, spaces

(yes, I've searched all around for a solution, and, if did I see it, I wasn't able to relate to my issue. I'm new to Python, sorry!)

I've got a work to do, and it says to me:
"User will input X and Y. Show a sequence from 1 to Y, with only X elements each line."

e.g 
2 4 as entrance

```
1 2

3 4
```

e.g 2 6

```
1 2

3 4

5 6
```

Okay... So, I thought on doing this:

```
line, final = input().split()
line = int(line)
final = int(final)
List = []
i = 0
total = (final // line)
spot = 0
correction = 0
k = 1

if i != final:
List = list(range(1, final + 1, 1))
i += 1

while k != total:
spot = line * k + correction
correction += 1
k += 1
list.insert(List, spot, '\n')

print(*List)
```

Ok. So I managed to build my List from 1 to the "final" var.
Also managed to find on which spots (therefore, var "spot") my new line would be created. (Had to use a correction var and some math to reach it, but it's 10/10)

So far, so good.
The only problem is this work is supposed to be delivered on URI Online Judge, and it DEMANDS that my result shows like this:

2 10 as entrance

```
1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

9 10
```

And, using the code I just posted, I get this as a result:

```
1 2

 3 4

 5 6

 7 8 

 9 10
```

Thus, it says my code is wrong. I've tried everything to remove those spaces (I think). Using sys won't work since it only prints one argument. Tried using join (but I could have done it wrong, as I'm new anyway)

Well, I've tried pretty much anything. Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can specify an `end` argument to your print statement. `for i in range(10): print(i, end='')` will print 0-9 all on the same line. Also, you can do `"".join(str(char) for char in my_list)` to get a concatenated version of your list without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the approach you're using is a result of a space being printed after each `"\n"` character in the series. While the idea was quite clever, unfortunately, I think this means you will have to take a different approach from inserting the newline character into the list.

Try this approach: (EDITED)

```
x, y = input().split()
x, y = int(x), int(y)

for i in range(1, y+1):
    if i % x == 0 or i == y:
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

Output for `3 11`

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11
```

Output for `2 10`

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Comment: Editing done. I believe this should satisfy the conditions. Surprisingly simple!

Comment: Made another edit, just in case the final newline matters.

Answer (score 1):

You have built a list that includes each necessary character, including the linefeed. Therefore, you have a list like this:

```
[1, 2, '\n', 3, 4, '\n'...]
```

When you unpack arguments to `print()`, it puts a separator between each argument, defaulting to a space. So, it prints `1`, then a space, then `2`, then a space, then a linefeed, then a space... And that is why you have a space at the beginning of each line.

Instead of inserting linefeeds into a list, chunk that list with `iter` and `next`:

```
>>> def chunks(x, y):
...     i = iter(range(1, y+1))
...     for row in range(y//x):
...             print(*(next(i) for _ in range(x)))
...     t = tuple(i)
...     if t:
...             print(*t)
...
>>> chunks(2, 6)
1 2
3 4
5 6
>>> chunks(2, 7)
1 2
3 4
5 6
7
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't mark everything here as an answer. I marked the simplest one for me to understand, yet, everyone here helped me a lot, including you, thanks a lot! I'll get your code and analyze it in a further moment for better understanding. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I split user input into two string then convert them into int and comapre if y greater than x by 2 because this is minimum for drawing your sequence 
Then i make a list from 1 to y 
And iterate over it 2 element for each iteration printing them

```
x,y=input().split()
if  int(y)>int(x)+2:
    s=range(1,int(y)+1)
    for i in range(0,len(s),2):
        print(' '.join(str(d) for d in s[i:i+2]))
```

result:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Comment: Maybe some explanation of what's wrong with the OP's code, and how this resolves it? You don't need to send a `range` object to `list` to get its length, by the way.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  explanation in your post cannot copy-past it now you posted while i am editing   :D

Comment: Wouldn't this actually output `'1 2'`? I think OP needs them to be printed as ints, not strings.

Comment: @sytech anyway i am just printing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that @HishamKaram

Comment: @sytech He has a problem with spaces only

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @HishamKaram, thank you again, I unfortunately can't mark everything here as an answer. I marked the simplest one for me to understand, yet, everyone here helped me a lot, including you, thanks a lot! I'll get your code and analyze it in a further moment for better understanding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndréCaruso i am here to let you understand this code

Answer (score 0):

Use itertools to take from an iterable in chunks:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def print_stuff(x,y):
...   it = iter(range(1, y + 1))
...   chunk = list(itertools.islice(it,X))
...   while chunk:
...     print(*chunk)
...     chunk = list(itertools.islice(it,X))
... 
>>> print_stuff(2,4)
1 2
3 4
>>>
```

And here:

```
>>> print_stuff(2,10)
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if URI has itertools, but thank you very much, I'll analyze what you did and try to incorporate from now on whatever I do! thank you again

Comment: @AndréCaruso what is URI? `itertools` is part of the Python standard library.

Comment: It's a online tool for college professors to assign works and jobs for you to do. You submit a code, select your language (between python2, 3, java, c, and some others) and they judge whether it's correct or not. I've tried importing some libraries before and it gave me an error, that's why I didn't use iter (I had read about it somewhere else)

Still, you helped me a lot, unfortunately, I can't mark everything here as an answer, but thank you very much!